# Removing DataGridView when cell is in edit mode prevents Form from closing

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

I think this is a bug in .NET (4.0 and 4.5) that I'm trying to workaround. I've created a small sample that should reproduce this issue.

1. Click the button
2. Edit a cell (a1 or a2 before the dgv is removed)
3. Wait for data to change to b1 and b2.
4. Then try closing the form.

I thought I could solve this by simply cancelling the edit on the current cell, but the form still cannot be closed. For some reason, e.Cancel is true.

```
class DForm : Form {

    Button btn = new Button { Text = "Test", Dock = DockStyle.Top };

    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

    public DForm() {

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Field1");
        table.Columns.Add("Field2");
        table.Rows.Add("a1", "a2");
        dgv.DataSource = table;

        Controls.Add(btn);
        Controls.Add(dgv);

        btn.Click += delegate {
            MessageBox.Show("Now edit a cell. After the dgv is swapped, try to close the form.");

            DataGridView dgv2 = new DataGridView() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
            table2.Columns.Add("Field1b");
            table2.Columns.Add("Field2b");
            table2.Rows.Add("b1", "b2");
            dgv2.DataSource = table2;

            Thread t = new Thread(o => {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Control c = (Control) o;
                c.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate {
                    if (dgv.IsCurrentCellInEditMode)
                        dgv.CancelEdit();

                    this.Controls.Remove(dgv);
                    dgv.Dispose();
                    this.Controls.Add(dgv2);
                });
            });
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start(this);
        };
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Cancel) {
            MessageBox.Show("why???");
            return;
        }

        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to call table.EndEdit()

Answer (score 3):

I could reproduce your problem with .NET 3.5 also. So far I couldn't come up with an explanation to this behavior. I'll update the answer when I find one.

`CancelEdit` only discards the changes but doesn't end the editing of the cell (but [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.canceledit(v=vs.110).aspx) says otherwise). You can just see this behavior if you keep the original `DataGridView` without replacing with other. The original value is reverted but the cell still is in edit mode.

If you want to discard and end the editing of the cell, use `CancelEdit` and `EndEdit` together like below. With this change the form could be closed.

```
dgv.CancelEdit();
dgv.EndEdit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `dgv.DataSource` to `null` worked for me :

```
if (dgv.IsCurrentCellInEditMode)
{
    dgv.CancelEdit();
    dgv.DataSource = null;
}
```